# Fixing spacing after removing stopwords

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tweets

I have run a code to remove stopwords, but the output has removed the space between the words.

The initial input before the stopword removal is like this:

```
form server happen
```

The word output looks like this:

```
formserverhappen
```

Code:

```
#Removing stopwords

def remove_stopwords(text,nlp,custom_stop_words=None,remove_small_tokens=True,min_len=2):
    # if custom stop words are provided, then add them to default stop words list
    if custom_stop_words:
        nlp.Defaults.stop_words |= custom_stop_words
    
    filtered_sentence = [] 
    doc=nlp(text)
    for token in doc:
        
        if token.is_stop == False: 
            
            # if small tokens have to be removed, then select only those which are longer than the min_len 
            if remove_small_tokens:
                if len(token.text)>min_len:
                    filtered_sentence.append(token.text)
            else:
                filtered_sentence.append(token.text)
    # if after the stop word removal, words are still left in the sentence, then return the sentence as a string else return null 
    return '  '.join(filtered_sentence) if len(filtered_sentence)>0 else None
#creating a spaCy object. 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["parser", "ner"])

#removing stop-words and short words from every row
negative.ctstring=negative.ctstring.apply(lambda x:remove_stopwords(x,nlp,{"mask","mandates",}))
```

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MbQX.png)

I looked that join but I can't figure out why the change is occuring.

Comment: Change `''.join` to `' '.join` so you put a space between the words.

Comment: I did that and it still happens. 
    return '  '.join(filtered_sentence) if len(filtered_sentence)>0 else None

Comment: I have added to python code for your review.

Comment: The code in the text is not the same as the screenshot. The text has two spaces, the screenshot has none.

Comment: If you have spaces in the `.join()` then that's not where the words are being combined. It must be SpaCy doing it.

Comment: Try doing `print(filtered_sentence)` to see what that is.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py:283: DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future. Please pass the result to `transformed_cell` argument and any exception that happen during thetransform in `preprocessing_exc_tuple` in IPython 7.17 and above.
  and should_run_async(code)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 print(filtered_sentence)
NameError: name 'filtered_sentence' is not defined

Comment: How can that be? it should be right before `return '  '.join(filtered_sentence) if len(filtered_sentence)>0 else None`

Comment: I have no idea. This is why I am so confused.

Comment: That error is impossible if you put it in the proper place. Clearly the variable exists because you don't get that error when calling `join()`.

Comment: I am not sure where else to put the join. The code above shows where i have the join

Comment: You don't need to put the join anywhere else. YOu just need to put that debugging statement before the join, so we can see what you're actually trying to join and figure out why you're not getting the result you want.

Comment: Instead of `token.text`, I'd recommend using the `token.text_with_ws` property which preserves the white space (see https://spacy.io/api/token)